# What causes a charged particle to follow circular motion in a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, plasma-physics

I would like to know why particles follow a circular path in a magnetic field, what path they trace and how this path is measured and controlled?

Comment: Charge and magnetism are really two sides of the same coin but they are perpendicular to one another

Comment: @Jaywalker  That's quite a vague comment.  And as-is it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @count_to_10 I think this is a terminology error, I have already proposed an edit to the question

Comment: @garyp you are right my comment doesn't make sense. what I meant to say was that a magnetic field will only affect the motion of a charge that is not moving parallel to its vector.

Comment: @Jaywalker If the problem was typing faster than thinking ... been there, done that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The motion of a charged particle in a magnetic field is the manifestation of the fundamental relationship between magnetism and electrostatic effects. Exactly why the fundamental forces are the way they are is still beyond modern day physics which is why it is hard to give a satisfactory answer to the first part of your question. It just has to be accepted that magnetism and charge are intrinsically linked without knowing the reason.

How the particle behaves in the field however is very well understood and the basis of tools such as the cyclotron. 
The force exerted on the particle as a result of the magnetic field is given by:

$F=qvBcos\theta$

Due to the fact that the vectors of the magnetic field, the motion of the particle and the force experienced by the particle are all perpendicular to one another, the force is directed at a right angle to the motion of the charge.

This means that the particle will follow a circular path (a spiral if it is not moving exactly perpendicular to the field).
Varying the path is also quite simple as any adjustment to the strength or direction of the magnetic field will result in a change of the force exerted on the charge.

Comment: Could you explain what  the gyro

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say " could you explain what the gyroradius is?" How is this circular motion of a charged particle  used to contain plasma in a tokamak?  Why  is a helical magnetic field  necessary? Isn't a horizontal  one  enough?